# Angular: Observable service doesn't get data from api

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, observable, angular7

I started to use `MatTableDataSource` instead of `DataSource` and I got a problem to get data from api. When I use `booking` object as const array, it works fine. But when I want to use the service, which will get data from api, unfortunately it doesn't work, and my `paginator` shows 0 elements. Below I put my files:

### booking-table.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import {BookingService} from "../../service/booking.service";

export interface BookingI {
  id: number;
  bookingDate: string;
  bookingTime: string;
  date: string;
  time: string;
  boardId: number;
  employeeId: number;
  personalData: string;
  phoneNumber: number;
  description: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-booking-table',
  templateUrl: './booking-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./booking-table.component.css'],
})

export class BookingTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<BookingI>;

  displayedColumns = ['id', 'personalData', 'phoneNumber'];

  booking: BookingI[] = [];

  constructor(private bookingService: BookingService) {

    this.bookingService.getAllBookings()
      .subscribe(value => this.booking = value);

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.booking);
    console.log(this.dataSource);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

### booking.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {Booking} from "../model/booking";
import {catchError} from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookingService {

  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getAllBookings(): Observable<Booking[]> {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/bookings';
    return this.http.get<Booking[]>(url)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('Error', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

### booking-table.component.html

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let booking">{{booking.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="personalData">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Dane klienta</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let booking">{{booking.personalData}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="phoneNumber">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Nr telefonu</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let booking">{{booking.phoneNumber}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let booking; columns: displayedColumns;">
    </tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Does someone can write what's wrong with my get method. Just to be clear, when I use DataSource it works fine, but when I use MatTableDataSource service get method doesn't work.

Comment: `this.booking`is populated **asynchronously**. If it was synchronous, the service would return an Observable. It would returnt the array directly. It returns an observable so that it can notify you, much later, that the bookings have finally been sent by the server. So you can only be sure that the bookings are there **inside** the callback function passed to subscribe(). BTW, since it's an **array** of booking**s**, you'd better name it `bookings`, not `booking`.

Comment: OK, do you have an idea what i should check? Or where I should look for problem? I don't get any error in browser, and i don't know what it's wrong.

Comment: Well, I have described the thing you did wrong and how to fix it in my previous comment. Have you read it? What don't you understand in that comment?

Comment: I understood that this.booking is populated asynchronously and i'll should populate it to synchronously.

Comment: No. You can't make an AJAX call synchronous. Again read my comment: you can only be sure that the bookings are there **inside the callback function passed to subscribe()**. So that's where you must initialize the DataSource, not right after you've sent the request, because at that point, the bookings have not been receied yet.

Comment: OK, i got this. I change my code to proposition from answer and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice is to use `constructor` only for injections, and to use hook methods, like `ngOnInit` for the rest. Try to replace your code by something like that:

```
constructor(private bookingService: BookingService) {
}

ngOnInit() {

    this.bookingService.getAllBookings().subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value);
        this.dataSource = value;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
}
```

Comment: It works correctly when i moved this: `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;` inside subscribe brackets.